# How can I tell the difference between good carbs and bad carbs?

Tags: nutrition, carbohydrate

How do you determine if something is good carb or bad carb?  Reason I ask is after a month of hardcore working out I realized my body has changed.  While I was eating five meals a day with very low carbohydrate I find myself now in need of six - seven meals daily else I feel dizzy.  I am ALOT leaner compare to pre-workout condition.  I was told to intake more carbohydrate but I don't want to over do it.  So, what's the best way to determine if food is good carb or bad carb?

I guess i should word it better.  Ok let's say if i were to go into a grocery store today and shop for "good carb" food what would i be looking for and what's the most obvious way to look for them? Besides simply reading the label, which fresh produce usually don't have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically a "good carb" indicates that the food has nutrients and is absorbed into the bloodstream slowly.

- **Whole**: Fibers, husks, and other materials provide fiber (which limits an insulin spike) and vitamins. (e.g. Choose brown rice over white rice)
- **Unrefined**: Refining processes typically remove nutrients. In addition, they tend to render foods such that they are absorbed faster. (e.g. Avoid regular white flour in favor of stone-ground, or better yet avoid flour altogether)
- **Complex**: Natural foods containing "complex carbohydrates" instead of sugars or starches have fiber and other material that helps slow the absorption into the bloodstream (e.g. Choose beans over potatoes)
- **Low-Glycemic**: The [glycemic index](http://www.glycemicedge.com/glycemic-index-chart/) (and the related glycemic load) is a measurement of how quickly foods are absorbed into the bloodstream. Low-glycemic is typically defined as foods with an index no higher than 30-50 (normalized against table sugar at 100).

Comment: awesome break down of carbohydrate.

Comment: i also heard that basically anything that is not white is considered good carb? is this true?

Comment: @kjy I don't know if would consider any of this some universal truth, but avoiding white foods is a good rule of thumb. (Healthy exceptions to this rule include cauliflower, eggs, and whole milk)

Comment: reminds me of a "theory" that a coworker of mine had that all healthy foods were brown.  So therefore, if it is brown it is healthy.  Triple chocolate fudge brownie with icing anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the difference between "good" and "bad" boils down to whether the carbs are "[simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monosaccharide)" or "[complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysaccharide)." In more modern days, the [glycemic index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycemic_index) is also a good measure of "goodness"

Comment: very simple way to look at carbs, but is there a visual way to determine what is simple or complex?

Comment: i also heard that basically anything that is not white is considered good carb? is this true?

Comment: @kjy112 No. Not the color specifically.  However, as a general rule, you could say that anything that can be turned in to a white carb can be considered bad (although that'll likely include some good carbs, while eliminating most/all bad carbs) i.e. Cauliflower is a good carb