# Calories vs Carbs

Tags: calories, carbohydrate

I am student trying to improve my overall health and fitness level. I do also want to lose weight. I am very busy between work, school, and other obligations so I do not exercise at all. However, recently began to incorporate walking for and hour in my daily routine. My biggest issue is my terribly limited diet.

I have a diagnosis of gastroparesis and IBS so I really tolerate starchy carbs better than fats and proteins. I also have issues digesting food like dairy, wheat, fibrous food/vegetables/fruits, etc. Most of my current diet consists of gf farina, gf bread, bananas, potatoes, soy products (soy milk, tofu).

**My main concern is:

Are the amount of carbs:protein:fats ratio making it difficult for me to lose

weight or is it the calories in our diet that ultimately matter? (I don't track

either one). I appreciate all and any advice! Thank you.**

Comment: Also related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-can-i-tell-the-difference-between-good-carbs-and-bad-carbs?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Physics dictates that if the energy you take in is less than your 'energy out', you will lose weight. You can lose weight eating 100% french fries, as long as your energy expenditure is greater than the calories you consume. All foods have a 'thermic effect', including carbs.

This said, it is *very* important to eat a balanced diet, this means a diet with the right amount of micronutrients and macronutrients for your goals.

You may have heard of If It Fits Your Macros (IIFYM), these days it's a bit misguided and there is a lot of misinformation associated with it, but basically if you track calories and macronutrients for your goals and eat at a modest calorie deficit, you WILL lose weight. 
Introducing more walking into your daily routine is a GREAT start too and well done, simple energy system work (like walking) with a modest calorie deficit and healthy food selection (of foods you can tolerate) is an ideal start to a weight loss journey.